# Are Samvada sooktham and aikyamathya sooktham the same?

Tags: vedas, mantras, rig-veda, upanishads, hymn

What is the difference between Samvada sooktha and Aikyamathya sooktha?

Answer (score 3):

'Samvāda' (संवादः) means conversation. In the Rig Veda samhitā, there are around 4 or 5 famous long conversations. Examples are:

- Yama and Yami (RV 10.10) starting with "ओ चित्सखायं सख्या ववृत्यां"
- Urvashi and Pururavā (RV 10.95) starting with "हये जाये मनसा तिष्ठ घोरे"
- Devas and Agni (RV 10.51) starting with "महत्तदुल्बं स्थविरं तदासीत्"
- Saramā (the female dog of the Devas) and Paṇis (RV 10.108) starting with "किमिच्छन्ती सरमा प्रेदमानट्"

'Aikamatya' (ऐकमत्य) means 'unity of thought'. In Rig Veda, typically the last suktam RV 10.191 is called the 'Sāmmanasya' (सांमनस्य) suktam, because it talks about having a consensus and unity in thought, intention, word and action.

It begins with "सं समिद्युवसे वृषन्नग्ने". The central mantras for unity are the second onwards:

> सं गच्छध्वं सं वदध्वं सं वो मनांसि जानताम् । देवा भागं यथा पूर्वे संजानाना उपासते ॥
> Move in unity, speak in unity, fully know each other's minds (i.e. be of one mind). Just as the Devas in ancient times being of one mind, obtained their share of the yajna.

Comment: here The meaning of Sam bliss that is apt.. because  unity is apparent or literal meaning.. if you replace bliss instead of unity you will get beutiful meaning. Lets move in bliss, speak out of bliss, let our mind stay in bliss. Like the gods who had obtained their bliss after doing required upsena.. there is no mention of share of yajna as you had stated is available in the verse

Comment: @PrasannaR The prefix 'sam' does not have the meaning of bliss, precisely because it is a prefix. It is attached to the verbs in the mantra (संगच्छध्वं, संवदध्वं, संजानतां). You cannot just dump random meanings on mantras as you like. It has the meaning of 'together' or 'collected'. I have strictly given Sayanacharya's explanation. He says, for example, परस्परं विरोधं परित्यज्य एकविधमेव वाक्यं ब्रूत for 'सं वदध्वं’. And for 'देवा भागं’ he says, यथा पुरातनाः देवा ऐकमत्यं प्राप्ता **हविर्भागं** उपासते यथास्वं स्वीकुर्वन्ति । No word in the entire suktam has any meaning of "bliss".

Comment: let me take the second part devas with one mind got their individual havirbhagam.. statement.. how does it relate samanya mansya living with unity of mind.. now unity of mind in getting havisu.. kriya.. unity of mind of people where no action is invovled.. what does it convey There is no relation between the two statment one is describing unity of devas act of receiving, does it mean to convey samnya mansu should be united in mind like devas while getting the  dana.. that is not coming out clearly from literal meaning of syanaacharya

Comment: @PrasannaR It is an analogy. The mantra is using the analogy of Devas being of one mind to successfully obtain their fruits of the yajna, to say that if we are also united we will be successful.